# updating iOS5 app to use auto layout and iOS8 baseline

Tags: ios, ios5, ios8, autolayout

I have an iOS 5 era app that I need to update to "modern" terms to be able to submit an update to the app store.  I am shooting for iOS 8 as a baseline using auto layout and size classes.

The base UI is a Tab Bar controller, each tab of which has a UINavigationController as its base.

MainWindow.xib is the main nib file used when opening the app.

I opened all the nibs and checked Use Autolayout and Use Size Classes.

The app runs, but always comes up as a 3.5" phone sized app, even on a 6 Plus (device or simulator).   I cannot find any constraints applicable nor any settings in any of the nibs that seem to affect this.

The Tab Bar itself seems stuck at the 3.5" size and I can find no constraints or settings on this.  The window and tab bar element themselves in the nib show the generic 600x600 / any-any size.

Comment: Frankly, at this point I would consider just targeting iOS9 so you can use UIStackView. Maybe more work now but it should pay off.

Comment: @Paul Cezane .  I need to update the app right away as a test setting it ships with is no longer valid and needs to be updated.  In addition, the app is a resource-drain in terms of generating sales income, so I want to do the minimum necessary to make it compliant and updatable.  It is a very specialized app with not a large potential user base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add launch images for each device size you want to support. That tells iOS that the app actually can be displayed at that size and resolution.

Additionally you will want to add @3x assets for the iPhone 6+.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I probably knew that long ago :) but all the projects I have been working on the last several years already, from the get-go, had the larger launch images and "just worked."   For now I am just going to support the 4" size and let it stretch out on the larger screen phones as this is a specialty app without a large potential client base and not worth the effort to support the different sized larger phones in more than the blown out 4" size.  Thanks!